# inserting date from form to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

here is my form code

*my database use date format

Im sure my code got no error, but as soon as i click upload button, the date come out only 0000-00-00

```
<form action="imageupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type="date" size="60" name="date" id="date"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />

    </form>
```

here is my image upload.php code

```
    fclose ($handle);
    // Commit image to the database

    $date = htmlentities($_POST['date']);
    $query = 'INSERT INTO user_post (date) VALUES ("' . date '")';

  if ( !(mysql_query($query,$link)) ) 
   {
      die('<p>Error writing image to database</p></body></html>');
   } 
   else 
   {
      header('Refresh: 2 ; url=imageShow.php');
   }
```

Comment: `$` sign is missing.

Comment: you are adding `date` missing `$`

Comment: $query = 'INSERT INTO user_post (date) VALUES ("' . $date. '")';

Comment: what do you mean no error? `("' . date '")'` and stop using mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first convert your date to `Y-m-d` format and also `$` is missing to **values date** it should be `$date` Try

```
$rawdate = htmlentities($_POST['date']);
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rawdate));
$query = "INSERT INTO user_post (date) VALUES ('$date')";
```

Comment: This code always insert date as 1970-01-01

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `$` sign to all php variables.

change

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO user_post (date) VALUES ("' . date '")';
```

to

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO user_post (date) VALUES ("' . $date. '")';
```

and make sure you are entering correct date format `(YYYY-MM-DD)` in text box at form.

**EDIT**

You are correct rasclatt

Comment: If you are going to use the period method, you need another period after `$date` -> `.$date.`

Answer (score 0):

date field in the database is `date` type or `datetime`. format of these are `yyyy-mm-dd`

try this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Date']));
$query = 'INSERT INTO user_post (date) VALUES ("' . $date '")';
```